# Calling another ViewModel using Caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have two views call them A and B. When a user performs a specific action on A, I want it to launch B. Both views should remain open.

A inherits Conductor  and I've tried to call ActivateItem but view B never opens.

What am I missing? Is this is correct way to call one view from another using Caliburn.micro?

Comment: Do you want to launch the B-view in another window? Or are you going to have multiple screens in one window?

Comment: I would like to launch it in a different window. Both A and B should be displayed in there own windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's the easiest solution if the B-view is supposed to be in a different window. I'm assuming that AViewModel is the 'shell' view model:

```
public class AViewModel // : Screen - that's optional right here ;)
{
    private readonly BViewModel bViewModel;
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

    public AViewModel(BViewModel bViewModel, IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this.bViewModel = bViewModel;
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
    }

    public void ShowB()
    {
        windowManager.ShowWindow(bViewModel); //If you want a modal dialog, then use ShowDialog that returns a bool?
    }
}
```

and the simplest of views (AView):

```
<Button Name="ShowB" Content="Show another window"/>
```

It will show the new window with `BView` when you click a button on `AView`.

Conductors are used to have multiple screens in one window (or, in different words, multiple panes on one screen). Sometimes it's `OneActive` (e.g. when implementing navigation in WPF) or `AllActive` when there are multiple screens available at once.

[Here's](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager/) a nice tutorial regarding some of the Caliburn.Micro's basics and that particular part describes the Window Manager.

Comment: Thanks that gives me what I need. That tutorial is well written and should help as well.

Comment: Hi @Patryk Cwiek. WIthout a button is there a way I can call a method in BViewmodel? The link you have provided is broken :(